# Sort pair in GoLang

Tags: sorting, go, key, key-value

I know how to sort key/value with data type:

```
map[1:a 2:c 0:b]
```

using `sort` package of GoLang. How can I sort a `Pair` like the following:

```
[{c 2} {a 1} {b 0}]
```

I want the whole pair to be sorted either according to key or value? End result:

```
[{a 1} {b 0} {c 2}]
```

this is sorted according to keys. Below is sorted according to values:

```
[{b 0} {a 1} {c 2}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement `Len`, `Swap` and `Less` for a custom type. An example is given here: https://gobyexample.com/sorting-by-functions

Here's how you could sort by key for your example: http://play.golang.org/p/i6-e4I7vih

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type Pair struct {
    Key   string
    Value int
}

type ByKey []Pair

func (s ByKey) Len() int {
    return len(s)
}

func (s ByKey) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}

func (s ByKey) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return s[i].Key < s[j].Key
}

func main() {
    pairs := []Pair{{"a", 1}, {"b", 0}, {"c", 2}}
    // Sort by Key
    sort.Sort(ByKey(pairs))
    fmt.Println(pairs) // [{a 1} {b 0} {c 2}]
}
```

Comment: I don't want sort key/value separately and display them, I want whole pair to be sorted together. Please see my edit.

Comment: @user2567857, I believe I understood you. I added a link to an example to my answer.

Comment: Incase, anyone wants to know how to sort according to `value`, just change `s[i].Key` and `s[j].Key` to `s[i].Value` and `s[i].Value` respectively.